# Links in php mail function fail

Tags: php, html, email, hyperlink

i'm trying to send an email using php mail function witch contains a hyperlink inside the body of the message, but it fails to send the mail, if i leave the link out it works just fine, my code:

```
$headers2=array(
'MIME-Version: 1.0',
'From: name',
'Content-Type: text/html'
);

$message2='
<div style="color:gray; text-decoration:underline; font-size:18px;">content content</div><a href="http://www.someurl.com/index.php?p=faq">FAQ</a></div>';

mail(''.$email.'','Thank you!',''.$message2.'',implode("\r\n", $headers2));
```

I'm using a godaddy server, witch like i said sends mails just fine unless it have a hyperlink in the content.

Comment: In what way does it fail?  Does the SMTP server return an error?  Does the SMTP server just silently ignore the message?  Does the recipient's mail account filter it as junk?  A lot of things can go wrong with email, very few of which have anything to do with the code.

Comment: In all seriousness, please stop using php's built-in `mail()` function. If you're sendinfg html emails in php, use a decent mailer class like phpMailer; it will save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: I just dont recieve the email at all

Answer (score 0):

Adding htmlentities() in the mail() function could help allow it through.

```
mail(''.$email.'','Thank you!',''.htmlentities($message2).'',implode("\r\n", $headers2));
```

Comment: If it's working without any HTML code in the subject, but not when it there is, it sounds like a client side problem. Check your spam/junk folder, as an email with just a link in the body might be seen as spam

Comment: i did it wasent there

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works perfectly with the hyperlinks. Check your server configurations

Comment: What should i be looking for in the server configurations? what might be the problem in your opinion?

Comment: you could try checking out your `sendmail` configurations.